# Where are user profile fields?

Tags: support, user-accounts, profile-page

Simple question, maybe even a simpler answer that is just escaping me:  for the autobiographer badge I am supposed to fill out all the user profile fields.  Where are these user profile fields?  I can't find them in my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

1. Click on your profile on the topbar (whilst on main page, not meta)
2. Click "edit" located under "Questions" (same line as your name)
3. Fill out items as necessary

Answer (score 3):

I image that you expected to provide something for "age", "location" and "website".

Note that there is nothing that enforces honesty in these values (e.g. my location) or that they are particularly important to you.